# MSBuild required environment variables

Tags: msbuild, environment-variables

I'm trying to setup .NET (C#) build from the command line. What is the list of environment variables that I need to set up in the MSDOS prompt before I can run `MSBuild.exe` from the command line?

The path to `MSBuild` executable would be the most obvious example. I cannot rely on setting variables from `MyComputer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Enviroment Variables` so I really need a full list if such list exists.

P.S. The build needs to be automated (command line), and I'm not using Visual Studio but building with .NET Framework (v3.5) only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the list of environment variables that I need to set up in the MSDOS prompt before I can run MSBuild.exe from the command line?

MSBuild has a set of [reserved properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx) that are used, but you don't need to do anything to set these up. Any variables that MSBuild needs will be setup within MSBuild. The only environmental variables you need to worry about are ones that **you** yourself require.

The physical path to MSBuild for your DOS script is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild
```

Comment: Of course the path will be different when targeting different versions of .NET.

Answer (score 6):

In the Visual Studio installation there is the batch file, `vsvars32.bat`, that will set the environment variables. If you want the list, then record the full list of environment variables before and after calling it, e.g. in a command line window:

```
set
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
set
```

And find the difference between the two lists.

(Your path to `vsvars32.bat` may vary...)

Comment: This does not seem to be the case for Visual Studio 2017. What happened?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set any environment variables when calling MSBuild. If your build scripts rely on a set of environment variables, then you will have to set those yourself. As for the default build process no special environment variables are required.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio comes with a program that will set all of the required command line variables for you in a command shell. It is recommended that you run that, this will give you `cmd` in a window that you can compile any of the different languages.

Comment: No can do. I'm using a different ways of setting the environment and I need a list of variables. I guess I need to go and dig up that batch file you mentioned

Answer (score -2):

There is no need for an environment variable. Just make sure you have this registry key set (note it is for 64-bit Visual Studio; use a slightly different path for Visual Studio 32-bit):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\4.0]
```

"MSBuildOverrideTasksPath"="C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\"

Then you can just type

```
msbuild
```

at the command prompt.